# Scraping data through changing Xpaths

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to scrape data, I am trying to scrape the product name, price and other information from the website, the product names are easy to access as they have similar xpath with only one tag that changes but for the prices the there are multiple changes to the tags.Is there an alternative to how I can scrape data without the xpath as class name and ID return an empty string.

````
driver= webdriver.Chrome('E:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
product_name=[]
product_price=[]
product_rating=[]
product_url=[]
driver.get('https://www.cdiscount.com/bricolage/climatisation/traitement-de-l-air/ioniseur/l-166130303.html#_his_')
for i in range(1,55):
    try :
        productname=driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="lpBloc"]/li['+str(i)+']/a/div[2]/div/span').text
        product_name.append(productname)
    except:
        print("none")
print(product_name)'''


Xpath of the price:

1st items price
```//*[@id="lpBloc"]/li[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]```

2nd items price
'''//*[@id="lpBloc"]/li[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[1]'''
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need to use hardcoded loop, rather identify unique xpath to identify parent element and then child element. Only ratings not avail for every product where you can use `try..except` block.

```
product_name=[]
product_price=[]
product_rating=[]
product_url=[]
driver.get('https://www.cdiscount.com/bricolage/climatisation/traitement-de-l-air/ioniseur/l-166130303.html#_his_')
for item in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="lpBloc"]//li[@data-sku]'):
    
        productname=item.find_element('xpath','.//span[@class="prdtTit"]').text
        product_name.append(productname)
        productprice=item.find_element('xpath','.//span[@class="price priceColor hideFromPro"]').text
        product_price.append(productprice)
        try:
          productRating=item.find_element('xpath','.//span[@class="c-stars-rating"]//span[@class="u-visually-hidden"]').text
          product_rating.append(productRating)
        except:
          productRating="Nan"
          product_rating.append(productRating)
          
        productUrl=item.find_element('xpath','.//a[.//span[@class="prdtTit"]]').get_attribute("href")
        product_url.append(productUrl)
        
print(product_name)
print(product_price)
print(product_rating)
print(product_url)
```

Comment: oh okay, I need to go through following sibling and on how to to use them,thank you for the help this answers my question correctly.